# Когда использовать path в link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= link_to 'Show', product %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete,
                  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
```

Почему для `show` и `destroy` не используется `product_path`, а в оcтальных случаях `path` используется

Answer (score 3):

Если в рельсовый хелпер `link_to` передать в качестве параметра ресурс (например, объект ActiveRecord) - хелпер сам построит путь до него. Для этого `link_to` передает параметры в метод `url_for`, который строит путь по указанным параметрам.

- Например: `<%= link_to 'Show', product %>` вернет путь `/products/1`, где `1` - это `id` ресурса.
- А если указать массив вида `[:admin, product]` - это создаст ссылку на `/admin/products/1`.
- А если - массив вида `[:admin, :products]` - создаст ссылку на `/admin/products`.
- Подобным образом вы можете задавать ссылки и в контроллерах, например, `redirect_to [:edit, product]`

---

В итоге в ваших вьюхах вы можете заменить...

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
```

...на...

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', [:edit, @product] %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', :products %>
```

...и результат не изменится.

Answer (score 3):

Маршруты, выдаваемые рельсовым хелпером `resources`, можно разделить на две группы:

Прямые действия (запрос с которым осмысленен с точки зрения семантики HTTP):

- index: GET коллекции
- create: POST ресурса
- show: GET ресурса
- update: PATCH ресурса (или PUT, хотя правильность семантики Rails тут под вопросом)
- destroy: DELETE ресурса

...и вспомогательные заглушки, которые нужны исключительно потому, что "надо рассказать браузеру, как совершить действие":

- new: интерфейс к create
- edit: интерфейс к update

**Прямые действия** используют просто путь к тому, над чем производится действие,  а само действие опознаётся из HTTP-метода.

Но для **"заглушек"** осмысленных HTTP-методов нет, поэтому они используют пути "с хвостиком". А поскольку хелпер возвращает только путь (но не метод!), *для прямых действий путь можно собрать прямо их объекта ресурса*, а для заглушек нужен хелпер или объект с "подсказкой".

Поскольку форма "подсказок" у маршрутной системы малоизвестна и имеет очень неочевидный синтаксис, её часто избегают в пользу хелперов, но это вопрос стиля.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще хэлпер `link_to` принимает путь, который можно получить при помощи path-хэлперов. Однако в том случае, когда редактируется или удаляется один объект ActionPack может автоматически сформировать путь. Ничто не мешает вам использовать хэлепер и в этом случае

```
<%= link_to 'Show', product_path(product) %>
```

Однако так получается длиннее.

Comment: Нет, не во всех, например, тут не получится products_path